# Serving static files on a url with parameters in Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, url-parameters

I am using the handlebars template engine with Express. When hitting endpoints without parameters, all my static files are served up. This is not the case when a parameter is included.

```
app.engine('.hbs', hbs(handlebarsOptions));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Here is the endpoint I am trying to use.

```
app.get('/projects/:name', function(req, res) {
  if(req.params.name === 'batteryapp') {
    res.render('project', {name: 'BatteryApp'});
  }
});
```

I have seen an example that apparently works if you use res.sendFile(). However, res.render() must be used when using a template engine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're not using absolute URL's (starting with a `/`) for the static resources in your template, so they are being requested relative to `/projects/batteryapp` instead of the root.

So instead of something like this:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Use this:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was my issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This also fixed my same issue. But this problem does not arise when i use get('/polls/all' ...). It arises only when I do get('/poll/:id'...). Can you please explain why?

Comment: @Sid24 not without more info